# PhoneGap/Cordova FileEntry.CopyTo resulting in Error Code 1000

Tags: cordova, android-camera, phonegap-build, android-file, phonegap

I am using PhoneGap version **cli-6.2.0** and I am encountering the following issue: With an Android Phone (Pixel XL) I got an error code 1000, if i choose an image from my photo library.

I am stuck here for a long time, can someone help? Thanks!

```
                imageURI = imageURI.split('?')[0];
                var fileEntry = new FileEntry();
                fileEntry.fullPath = imageURI; // --> file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myapp/cache/IMG_20170822_1111111.jpg

                window.requestFileSystem(window.LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
                    try {
                        fileSystem.root.getDirectory("Android/data/com.myapp/tmpphotos", { create: true, exclusive: false }, function(dir) { 
                            try {
                                var uniqName = utilities.GuidGenerator.generate()+'.jpg'; //->some GUID unique name
                                fileEntry.copyTo(dir, uniqName, function(entry) {
                                    // never executed here
                                    options.handlers.success(entry.toURI());
                                }, function(e){ alert(e.code); }); //-> error 1000 alarted here 
                            }
                            catch (e) {}

                        }, options.handlers.failure); 
                    }
                    catch(e) {
                        options.handlers.failure();
                    }

                }, options.handlers.failure);
```

Also this is my PhoeGapBuild config:

```
 <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" source="npm"></plugin>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" source="npm" />
```

Comment: OK, I actually figured out like 10 minutes after posting this question - the problem is I need to use `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageURI, function success(fileEntry)` to get my file entry first!